# Checking a Variable Type For Code Analysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

What is the correct way to check a variable's type in a Roslyn code analyzer? I am registering for a `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` node and I can get the type, but I am not certain the correct way to check that it is a type I care about.

I found a way to do it by checking the display string, but I am wondering if there is a more correct way to accomplish this.  For example, here is code that is trying to check for an ArrayList creation.

```
private static void SyntaxValidator(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var creation = (ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

    var variableType = creation.Type as IdentifierNameSyntax;

    if (variableType == null)
        return;

    var variableTypeInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(context.Node);

    if (variableTypeInfo.Type != null && variableTypeInfo.Type.ToDisplayString().Equals("System.Collections.ArrayList"))
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, creations.GetLocation(), ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal pattern for doing this is to use `Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName()`, and then compare that `ITypeSymbol` with The one you got back from `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo()`.

Note: Make sure to use `.Equals` to compare `ITypeSymbol` instances, as some of them do not guarantee reference identity.

See: http://sourceroslyn.io/Roslyn.Diagnostics.Analyzers/R/fee46febeb0be269.html for an example of an analyzer that does this.

Comment: the link is broken. Could you edit the answer to include the updated link?