# How to create a Roslyn ITypeSymbol for an arbitrary type?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I can use a **SyntaxGenerator** to generate a parameter of type **Int32** like so...

```
var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(document);
var paramType = generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_Int32);
var param = generator.ParameterDeclaration("MyParam", paramType);
```

What equivalent code should I use to create a parameter of type **Dataset**?

I presume I need to create an **ITypeSymbol** to pass to the **generator.TypeExpression**, but how to do this?

Comment: In what context do you want to do this? Do you have access to a semantic model or a compilation? If so, then you can use `SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName()` to get the `TypeSyntax` from any type name. And then, you can get the type symbol going through the semantic model.

Comment: Understanding that I'm pretty new to Roslyn... 

I was trying to do this from within the context of DiagnosticAnalyzers, CodeFixProviders and RefactoringProviders, but being new to Roslyn, I'm not sure what I have at my disposal in this scenario.

I was hoping to achieve this in a language-agnostic way, hence the use of a SyntaxGenerator rather than a SyntaxFactory, although if a way can be found to get a reference to the correct SyntaxFactory at runtime, then that might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a `Compilation`, you can use [`GetTypeByMetadataName`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/2.0.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation/GetTypeByMetadataName(System.String)), as explained in [this blog post](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/working-with-types-in-your-analyzer/) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31358698/41071):

```
var dataSetType = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Data.DataSet");
var paramType = generator.TypeExpression(dataSetType);
var param = generator.ParameterDeclaration("MyParam", paramType);
```

Comment: So given that I am within either a DiagnosticAnalyzer, CodeFixProvider or a RefactoringProvider, where can I get a Compilation from?

Comment: In an analyzer, you should be able to get it from an analysis context. I would guess it's similar for the other situations.

Comment: Doesn't look like the other 2 have that. However they do have a Document.Project.GetCompilationAsync method which seems to be as good. :)