# Roslyn code generation, how to create a type expression for a given type

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to generate code using Roslyn.  I create a method like this:

```
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);

var parameters = new SyntaxNode[] { generator.ParameterDeclaration("MyParam", generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_Boolean))};

var body = ...

var method = generatpr.MethodDeclaration(
   "MyMethod", 
   parameters,
   null, 
   null,
   Accessibility.Public,
   DeclarationModifiers.Virtual,
   new SyntaxNode[] { body});
```

My question is, how do I create parameters of other types like Guid, or other structs or classes?  And can I do it in a way that is language agnostic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Roslyn ITypeSymbol for an arbitrary type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356807/how-to-create-a-roslyn-itypesymbol-for-an-arbitrary-type)

Comment: The closest thing that might help me is Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName, but I need an instance of a Compilation object.  How do I get that?

Comment: default literal

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - I saw that too, but it requires a Compilation.  Because I am generating code, I have a SyntaxGenerator instance, and I have an instance of a Type object, so I used the SyntaxGenerator.IdentifierName() function, and passed in the FullName property of the Type instance.

Comment: I know it may not be applicable for your use case, but really just in case, I wanted to mention that instead of `SyntaxGenerator` you can use a static class [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.11.0) - it has more methods and doesn't require a workspace to function.

Answer (score 0):

yntaxGenerator instance, and I have an instance of a Type object, so I used the SyntaxGenerator.IdentifierName() function, and passed in the FullName property of the Type instance.

```
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);

var parameters = new SyntaxNode[] { generator.ParameterDeclaration("MyParam", generator.IdentifierName(typeParameter.FullName))};

var body = ...

var method = generatpr.MethodDeclaration(
   "MyMethod", 
   parameters,
   null, 
   null,
   Accessibility.Public,
   DeclarationModifiers.Virtual,
   new SyntaxNode[] { body});
```