# Substituting (Dictionary<string, ITypeSymbol> typeParameterValues) into ITypeSymbol in all cases

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a dictionary of type parameter values:

```
ImmutableDictionary<string, ITypeSymbol> typeParameterValues;
```

How can with an ITypeSymbol I substitute those type parameters in:

Eg. `List<T>` -> `List<string>` (if T is string)

Eg. `Dictionary<K, V>.ValueCollection` -> `Dictionary<string, int>.ValueCollection` (if K is string and V is int)

So far I have been able to make the first example work with the following code:

```
static ITypeSymbol SubstituteGenericArgs (ITypeSymbol type) => type switch {
    ITypeParameterSymbol tps => typeParameterValues[tps.Name]
    INamedTypeSymbol nts when nts.IsGeneric => nts.ConstructedFrom.Construct(
        nts.TypeParameters.Select(SubstituteGenericArgs).ToArray()
    ),
    INamedTypeSymbol ngts when !ngts.IsGeneric => ngts
};
```

I know I can do `nts.ContainingType` but the problem is once I have substituted the correct type arguments into the containing type, there is no way to get the original type using the new containing type that I have found.

Comment: Can you format your code to make it more readable?

Comment: I did my best._

Comment: Do my edits help?  If not, reject/revert them.

Comment: So you're asking about, when `nts.ContainingType.IsGeneric` how to tell which one of `SubstituteGenericArgs(nts.ContainingType).GetMembers(nts.Name)` is the same member as `nts`? Perhaps by comparing `.OriginalDefinition` ?

Comment: Take a look here: [How to create a Roslyn ITypeSymbol for an arbitrary type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356807/how-to-create-a-roslyn-itypesymbol-for-an-arbitrary-type)

Comment: What I want is given a Dictionary<string, ITypeSymbol> to substitute all generic parameter types into an ITypeSymbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up:

```
public record GenericContext (Dictionary<string, ITypeSymbol> typeParameterValues)
{
    public ITypeSymbol SubstituteGenericArgs (ITypeSymbol type) => type switch
    {
        INamedTypeSymbol nts when nts.ContainingType is {} ct && ct.IsGenericType => SimpleSubstituteGenericArgs(
            SubstituteGenericArgs(ct).GetMembers().OfType<INamedTypeSymbol>().Single(
                gv => gv.OriginalDefinition == nts.OriginalDefinition
            )
        ),
        _ => SimpleSubstituteGenericArgs(type)
    };

    public ITypeSymbol SimpleSubstituteGenericArgs(ITypeSymbol type) => type switch
    {
        ITypeParameterSymbol tps => typeParameterValues[tps.Name],
        INamedTypeSymbol nts when nts.TypeArguments.Length == 0 => nts,
        INamedTypeSymbol nts when nts.TypeArguments.Length >  0 => nts.ConstructedFrom.Construct(
            nts.TypeArguments.Select(SubstituteGenericArgs).ToArray()
        )
    };
}
```

Thanks [@Jeremy Lakeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139809/jeremy-lakeman).

See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AIlKBw

Let me know if you think of any improvements. I thought this would be a built-in feature.